# AngularJS directives and require

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive that is getting more and more complicated. So I decided to split it up into parts.

The directive itself loaded a garment SVG graphic, when the SVG loaded it then ran a configure method which would apply a design, applied picked colours (or database colours if editing) and other bits and pieces.

As I said, it was all in one directive, but I have now decided to separate the logic out.
So I created my first directive:

```
.directive('configurator', function () {

    // Swap around the front or back of the garment
    var changeView = function (element, orientation) {

        // If we are viewing the front
        if (orientation) {

            // We are viewing the front
            element.addClass('front').removeClass('back');
        } else {

            // Otherwise, we are viewing the back
            element.addClass('back').removeClass('front');
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            garment: '=',
            onComplete: '&'
        },
        require: ['configuratorDesigns'],
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/directives/kit.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

            // Configure our private properties
            var readonly = attrs.hasOwnProperty('readonly') || false;

            // Configure our scope properties
            scope.viewFront = true;
            scope.controls = attrs.hasOwnProperty('controls') || false;
            scope.svgPath = 'assets/garments/' + scope.garment.slug + '.svg';

            // Apply the front class to our element
            element.addClass('front').removeClass('back');

            // Swaps the design from front to back and visa versa
            scope.rotate = function () {

                // Change the orientation
                scope.viewFront = !scope.viewFront;

                // Change our view
                changeView(element, scope.viewFront);
            };

            // Executes after the svg has loaded
            scope.loaded = function () {

                // Call the callback function
                scope.onComplete();
            };
        }
    };
})
```

This is pretty simple in design, it gets the garment and finds the right SVG file and loads it in using ng-transclude.
Once the file has loaded a callback function is invoked, this just tells the view that it is on that it has finished loading.

There are a few other bits and pieces that you should be able to work out (changing views, etc).

In this example I am only requiring one other directive, but in the project there are 3 required directives, but to avoid complications, one will suffice to demonstrate my problem.

My second directive is what is needed to apply the design. It looks like this:

```
.directive('configuratorDesigns', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ConfiguratorDesignsDirectiveController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            // Get our private properties
            var garment = scope.$eval(attrs.garment),
                designs = scope.$eval(attrs.configuratorDesigns);

            // Set our controller designs array
            controller.designs = designs;

            // If our design has been set, watch it for changes
            scope.$watch(function () {

                // Return our design
                return garment.design;

            }, function (design) {

                // If we have a design
                if (design) {

                    // Change our design
                    controller.showDesign(element, garment);
                }
            });

        }
    }
})
```

The controller for this directive just loops through the SVG and finds the design that matches the garment design object. If it finds it, it just hides the others and shows that one.
The problem I have is that this directive is unaware of the SVG loading or not. In the "parent" directive I have the scope.loaded function which is executed when the SVG has finished loading.
The "parent" directive's template looks like this:

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
<div ng-include="svgPath" onload="loaded()"></div>
<a href="" ng-click="rotate()" ng-if="controls"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>
```

So my question is this:
How can I get the required directives to be aware of the SVG loaded state?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, $rootScope.broadcast should help you out. Just broadcast when the loading is complete. Publish a message from the directive you are loading the image. On the directive which needs to know when the loading is complete, listen for the message.

Comment: listen using watch? does that mean all my directives that will "require" this one need to use a similar watch?

Comment: When using broadcast just do $rootscope.broadcast("your_message_name"). You need to use $rootscope.on("your_message_name",function(){}) to listen to the particular your_message_name. your_message_name can be anything unique. The function is what gets executed when your message is received.  Does that answer your question?